# Redirect ranges of IPs in JavaScript (no .htaccess)

Tags: javascript, redirect, ip

I'm trying to redirect anyone viewing my blog from certain IP addresses (or ranges of IP addresses) to a different page. I found something that works for individual IP addresses, but I can't figure out how to block ranges of IP addresses - like 123.123.123.*

Here's the script:

```
<!-- check incoming IP address -->
<script type = "text/javascript" src="http://l2.io/ip.js?var=ip"></script>

<!-- redirect list -->
<script type = "text/javascript">
        window.onload = init();
        function init() {
            var blocklist = ["10.20.30.40","50.60.70.80"];
            for (var i = 0; i < blocklist.length; i++) {
                if (blocklist[i] == ip) {
                    window.location.replace('http://fakeblog.com/');
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
</script>
```

I've found some good advice for modifying .htaccess but I don't have access to that file. Thanks!

Comment: Where does the variable `ip` come from?

Comment: You should probably do this in the server code, not on the client. The client is likely to be behind a firewall or NAT, so the local IP is not its public IP.

Comment: The variable ip comes from a different script - I'll edit it in. That script just grabs the viewer's IP address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a regular expression instead of an array:

```
var blocklist = /^(10\.20\.30\.40|50\.60\.70\.80|123\.123\.123\..*)$/;
if (ip.match(blocklist)) {
    window.location.replace('http://fakeblock.com/');
}
```

Comment: I'm using this regular expression now. How can I make sure it catches all IP addresses starting with 123.123.123, meaning everything from 123.123.123.0 to 123.123.123.255 ?

Comment: Ah wait nevermind. I'm using this: var warnlist = /^(123\.123\.123\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?))$/;

Comment: `.*` at the end of the regexp matches anything. There's no need to be so specific.

Answer (score 0):

I would write a function to match IP's, that accepts wildcards.

```
/**
* Matches two ip's, supports the use of "wildcard", ex 192.168.*.*
*
* If an array of IP addresses is passed as the second argument, this
* function will return if any of them match.
*
* @param string A decimal separated IPv4 address
* @param string/[string] A, or an array of, decimal separated IPv4 addresses to match the first IP address against.
*/
function matchIP(ip, ipMatch) {
    if (ipMatch instanceof Array) {
        for (singleIpMatch in ipMatch) {
            if (matchIP(ip, singleIpMatch)) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    ipMatchParts = ipMatch.split('.');
    ipParts = ip.split('.');

    // IP is invalidly formatted 
    if (ipParts.length !== 4) {
        return false;
    }
    // IP match is invalidly formatted
    if (ipMatchParts.length !== 4) {
        return false;
    }

    matched = true;
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        if (ipParts[i] === '*') continue;
        if (ipMatchParts[i] === '*') continue;
        if (ipParts[i] === ipMatchParts[i]) continue;
        matched = false;
        break;
    }
    return matched
}
```

The code is tested and works, plugged into your example, it would look something like:

```
<!-- check incoming IP address -->
<script type = "text/javascript" src="http://l2.io/ip.js?var=ip"></script>

<!-- redirect list -->
<script type = "text/javascript">
        window.onload = init();
        function init() {
            var blocklist = ["10.*.*.*","11.87.70.*"]; // For example
            for (var i = 0; i < blocklist.length; i++) {
                if (matchIP(ip, blocklist[i])) {
                    window.location.replace('http://fakeblog.com/');
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
</script>
```

NB!

If the redirect is for security reasons, you should never do it on the client side. For example, the client may not be running the JavaScript at all, remember that everything that happens on the client side is a choice, so never do security stuff on the client end.